# How to implement filter_complex on the PHP-FFMpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

How to using **filter_complex** on the **PHP-FFMpeg**? I need to implement the following FFMpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=start=10:end=11,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=20:end=21,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b]; \
  [a][b]concat[c]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=30:end=31,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=40:end=41,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[f]; \
   [d][f]concat[g]; \
 [c][g]concat[out1]" -map [out1] testout.mp4
```

Comment: Don't know anything about ffmpeg-php, but you can simplify the ffmpeg command: `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=10:end=11,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a];[0:v]trim=start=20:end=21,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[0:v]trim=start=30:end=31,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[c];[0:v]trim=start=40:end=41,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d];[a][b][c][d]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[out1]" -map [out1] testout.mp4`